# How to create a rectangle with one side stroke only in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

How to create a rectangle with stroke only on one side of the rectangle ?

By default the stroke is applied to all sides of the rectangle.

Answer (score 13):

Partial strokes are not part of the Inkscape SVG format, so you have to build them yourself:

1. Create a version of the desired rectangle with strokes on all 4 sides.
2. *Duplicate* it.
3. Turn off the stroke for one of the rectangles (A) and the fill for the other ones (B).
4. *Lower* rectangle A behind rectangle B, if it isn’t already.
5. Switch to *Edit path by nodes* (<kbd>F2</kbd>).
6. Use *Convert selected object to path* on rectangle B.
7. Select the side of rectangle B opposite to the desired one and use *Delete Segment between two non-endpoint nodes* and *Delete selected nodes.*

Comment: clarification for a beginner: could you mention how you get to step 6,  Delete Segment between two non-endpoint nodes and Delete selected nodes? Thanks!

Comment: @Matifou: See my edit. You find those options in the *Edit path by nodes* interface. Hover the buttons to find the right ones.

Comment: **Convert selected object to path** is now named **Object to Path**, or Shift-Ctrl-C. It is roughly in the middle of the path-editing buttons.